# using tanh as activation function in MNIST dataset in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, mnist, activation-function

I am working on simple MLP neural network for MNIST dataset using tensorflow as my homework. in the question we should implement a multilayer perceptron with tanh as activation function. I should use the data label with [-1,+1].For example for number 3 we have:

```
[-1,-1,-1,+1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1]
```

I know that for sigmoid function we can use on_hot such as:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)
```

in order to putting data in [0,1] like the following for number 3:

```
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

how can I encode label between [-1 ,+1].
thanks in advance for every help

Comment: May I ask, why do you want to do that ?

Comment: because using when we are using the tanh, we should put values in this range@JérémyBlain

Comment: Yeah I understand why you want to use tanh, but why the data are [-1; +1] ? Is it a requirement ? The data were saved this way ?

Comment: yeah, in fact in the question it has been said that putting the value of active class to one and all another to -1.

Comment: That's a very awkward requirement. The reason for one-hot encoding with 0s and 1s is that this is the format which is expected by the common form of cross-entropy losses. (Also, this has nothing to do with logsig or tanh, for multiclass classification, the output layer usually uses a softmax.)

Comment: Neither sigmoid or tanh are typically used for multi-class classification, so I don't get what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 2):

Unnecessary downvotes to the question. BTW.. if I understood it correctly, here's the answer.

What I understood is, instead of using sigmoid, you have to use tanh and so you want the output data in format of +1s and -1s instead of 0s and 1s.

Note that one hot encoding is specifically designed for getting outputs of 1s and 0s. That's why it is called one hot encoding - it outputs 1 for right answer and 0 for others.

Now, there is no built-in function to get the output you want. But I prefer a short and simple way by writing my own code. Don't get afraid - that's only 1 line of code.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0])
a[a==0]=-1
```

The output is:

```
array([1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1])
```

You can use the same.. Take the one hot encoding labels as output using your code and then use this one line of code to get what you want.

```
a[a==0]=-1
```

Thank you..